# Problem displaying Farsi/Persian strings in CentOS 7

Tags: php, laravel, centos7

I have a simple function in my Laravel application that is supposed to return a string value based on a given input. The function works correctly when the input is in English, but it returns an empty string when the input is in Farsi/Persian. Here's the code for the function:

```php
function nameType($type)
{
    switch ($type) {
        case 'DEFECTIVE':
            return 'DEFECTIVE';
            break;
        case 'HEALTHY':
            return 'سالم'; 
            break;
        default:
            # code...
            break;
    }
}
```

I'm running this code on a CentOS 7 server, and I've tried adding the following settings to my php.ini file, but it didn't solve the problem:

```
default_charset = "utf-8";
mbstring.internal_encoding = UTF-8
```

In addition, when I try to return a JSON response in Farsi/Persian, Laravel gives me the following error:

```
"Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded"
```

I've also tried using the following functions within my code, but they didn't solve the issue either:

```php
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");

mb_convert_encoding('سالم', 'UTF-8', 'auto');
// Output: ؟؟؟؟

utf8_encode('سالم');
// Output: ÓÇáã

iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT', 'سالم');
// Error: iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string
```

I would appreciate any suggestions or solutions that could help me resolve this issue and correctly display Farsi/Persian strings in my Laravel application. Thank you.

In the text of the question, I described the efforts I made.